# Using AJAX to update multiple fields from SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. I have a dropdown box at the start of a form for office names being populated from an sql table. Depending on which office the user selects, I want the other fields to be filled out with the corresponding information for that record. I used the w3schools php ajax database page as a my guide but it only shows how to update one id in the page and I need to update the input field for address, city, state, zip, and contact.

Here's the relevant code which isn't working. The Code for to trigger the script for the dropdown:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showOffice(this.value)" class="field select" tabindex="1" >
```

The Script on that page:

```
<script>
function showOffice(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("practice_name").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("zip").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("practice_name").innerHTML=xmlhttp.practice_name;
document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML=xmlhttp.contact;
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=xmlhttp.address;
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlhttp.city;
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.state;
document.getElementById("zip").innerHTML=xmlhttp.zip;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getoffice.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And then my getoffice.php code:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];


$host="********"; // Host name 
$db_username="******"; // Mysql username 
$db_password="******"; // Mysql password 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password"); 
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"*****");
$sql="SELECT * FROM initial_practice WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
var practice_name = <? echo $row['practice_name']; ?>
var contact = <? echo $row['contact']; ?>
var address = <? echo $row['address']; ?>
var city = <? echo $row['city']; ?>
var state = <? echo $row['state']; ?>
var zip = <? echo $row['zip']; ?>
<?
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: w3schools has lots of incorrect information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. For any of you having the same trouble here's a fix.

php code:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$name = $row['practice_name'];
$contact = $row['contact_name'];
$address = $row['address'];
$city = $row['city'];
$state = $row['state'];
$zip = $row['zip'];

echo $name."#".$contact."#".$address."#".$city."#".$state."#".$zip;
```

On-page Script:

```
function showOffice(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("practice_name").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("zip").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{

    if(xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = xmlhttp.responseText.split("#");
        var name = decodeURIComponent(data[0]);
        var contact = decodeURIComponent(data[1]);
        var address = decodeURIComponent(data[2]);
        var city = decodeURIComponent(data[3]);
        var state = decodeURIComponent(data[4]);
        var zip = decodeURIComponent(data[5]);
        document.initialpractice.practice_name.value = name;
        document.initialpractice.contact.value = contact;
        document.initialpractice.address.value = address;
        document.initialpractice.city.value = city;
        document.initialpractice.state.value = state;
        document.initialpractice.zip.value = zip;
    }
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getoffice.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, it's a bit more lines but as long as you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you aren't using the response text back correctly. This can be fixed in a couple steps. The AJAX request pulls back everything that is printed out from getoffice.php.

**First**

We're gonna want to change these lines on the on-page script from this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("practice_name").innerHTML=xmlhttp.practice_name;
        document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML=xmlhttp.contact;
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=xmlhttp.address;
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlhttp.city;
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.state;
        document.getElementById("zip").innerHTML=xmlhttp.zip;
    }
}
```

To something a bit easier (I tend to separate readyState and status if statements, my delusional belief that it can randomly fail when combined):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
};
```

Now we're simply evaluating all we get back from the request. Also, note that I added a semi-colon to the end of the onreadystatechange function.

**Second**

Change the following lines in getoffice.php from:

```
var practice_name = <? echo $row['practice_name']; ?>
var contact = <? echo $row['contact']; ?>
var address = <? echo $row['address']; ?>
var city = <? echo $row['city']; ?>
var state = <? echo $row['state']; ?>
var zip = <? echo $row['zip']; ?>
```

To:

```
document.initialpractice.practice_name.value = <?php echo $row['practice_name']; ?>
document.initialpractice.contact.value = <?php echo $row['contact']; ?>;
document.initialpractice.address.value = <?php echo $row['address']; ?>;
document.initialpractice.city.value = <?php echo $row['city']; ?>;
document.initialpractice.state.value = <?php echo $row['state']; ?>;
document.initialpractice.zip.value = <?php echo $row['zip']; ?>;
```

Now, when we get the response back from the server, the javascript will evaluate the above response appropriately and fill in the fields. At least it should, providing the query doesn't fail.

Also, you can change `mysqli_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, since you only need the associative array.

**Note:** We could have solved the problem by just adding `eval(xmlhttp.responseText);` below the readyState/status checks and removing `xmlhttp.` in front of all the innerHTML variables.

Comment: I appreciate your help and though this makes perfect sense, still no luck. Do I have to do anything with my original check of when str==""?

Comment: You hadn't posted your full html, I was correcting your use of AJAX, check the last code block edit of getoffice.php.